# How to define a class label in matlab using arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, class, label

So I have this 720 x 6 matrix. Now I formed this matrix by vertically concatenating 9 arrays of 80 x 6 dimension. Is there a way I can define a label to identify these different arrays inside my concatenated matrix

e.g

Matrix A is a 80x6 matrix. Matrix B is another 80X6 matrix

When I vertically concatenate both A and B it forms a 160x6 matrix say ConcatAB matrix.

How can I know which vectors inside ConcatAB matrix correspond to either A matrix or B matrix.

Can I do this with class label?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an  extra dimension to store the IDs? For your case you can go to the third dimension to store all of the data into a "concatenated matrix".

For your example, the code would look something like this -

```
%%// Original matrices
MatA = rand(80,6);
MatB = rand(80,6);

%%// Final matrix to store all individual matrices
MatAB(:,:,1) = MatA;
MatAB(:,:,2) = MatB;
```

The final "concatenated matrix" would be of size `80x6x2`. If you have 9 such matrices, it would become `80x6x9`. As an example, to access MatA's (2,4) element, you can get it from MatAB(2,4,1) and MatB's (2,4) element would be at MatAB(2,4,2).

Basically you are storing the ID information as indices. If you strictly have to store some string information, you must look into converting the matrices to cell  arrays.